# Split data from aggregate to 2 arrays

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following schema:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
const ocrLogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['id', 'dl'],
    },
    caseId: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    eventName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['connect', 'disconnect', 'disconnect_type'],
    },
    disconnectType: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        enum: [
            'calling webhook',
            'calling webhook because of timeout',
            'client namespace disconnect',
            'server namespace disconnect',
            'transport close',
            'ping timeout',
            'transport error',
        ],
    },
    device: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        enum: [0, 1],
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const OCRLog = mongoose.model('OCRLog', ocrLogSchema);

module.exports = OCRLog;
```

I count number of documents for each `disconnectType` and return it as an array.
As you can see in the model schema, these are the `disconnectType`s:
'calling webhook',
'calling webhook because of timeout',
'client namespace disconnect',
'server namespace disconnect',
'transport close',
'ping timeout',
'transport error'.

So, typical return value would be: `[5,7,3,6,8,3,2]` for example. Each cell counts number of documents in the database of each `disconnectType`.

Now, As you can see there is field `device`. I want to split this array by the `device`. So now the return value would be:

```
{
    '0': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    '1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
}
```

How can I do it?

This is my code, which returns only array of numbers (without the split):

```
const getIDsOCRDisconnectTypesData = async (startDate, endDate) => {
    const ocrDisconnectTypesData = await OCRLog.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                timestamp: {
                    $gte: moment(new Date(startDate)).tz('Asia/Jerusalem').startOf('day').toDate(),
                    $lte: moment(new Date(endDate)).tz('Asia/Jerusalem').endOf('day').toDate()
                },
                type: 'id',
                eventName: 'disconnect_type',
            },
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '1',
                'calling webhook': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'calling webhook'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                'calling webhook because of timeout': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'calling webhook because of timeout'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                'client namespace disconnect': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'client namespace disconnect'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                'server namespace disconnect': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'server namespace disconnect'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                'transport close': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'transport close'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                'ping timeout': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'ping timeout'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
                'transport error': {
                    $sum: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'transport error'] },
                            1,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                },
            }
        },
    ]);

    if (ocrDisconnectTypesData.length === 0) {
        return new Array(8).fill(0);
    }

    delete ocrDisconnectTypesData[0]._id;

    return Object.values(ocrDisconnectTypesData[0]);
}
```

Comment: you need to `$group` to group them based on device

Comment: @AbishekKumar If you do have an idea, I'd like you to try to answer. Cause I've been trying anything for hours with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked on my device:

```
const ocrDisconnectTypesData = await OCRLog.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            timestamp: {
                $gte: moment(new Date(startDate)).tz('Asia/Jerusalem').startOf('day').toDate(),
                $lte: moment(new Date(endDate)).tz('Asia/Jerusalem').endOf('day').toDate()
            },
            type: 'id',
            eventName: 'disconnect_type',
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$device',
            'calling webhook': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'calling webhook'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'calling webhook because of timeout': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'calling webhook because of timeout'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'client namespace disconnect': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'client namespace disconnect'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'server namespace disconnect': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'server namespace disconnect'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'transport close': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'transport close'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'ping timeout': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'ping timeout'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'transport error': {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ['$disconnectType', 'transport error'] },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
        }
    },
]);
```

Also the output of the query was something like:

```
[{
  "_id" : 0,
  "calling webhook" : 1.0,
  "calling webhook because of timeout" : 0.0,
  "client namespace disconnect" : 0.0,
  "server namespace disconnect" : 0.0,
  "transport close" : 0.0,
  "ping timeout" : 0.0,
  "transport error" : 0.0
},
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "calling webhook" : 1.0,
  "calling webhook because of timeout" : 0.0,
  "client namespace disconnect" : 0.0,
  "server namespace disconnect" : 0.0,
  "transport close" : 0.0,
  "ping timeout" : 0.0,
  "transport error" : 0.0
}]
```